# extjs 4 : filling model data into combobox from PHP + MySql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, extjs, extjs4

```
Ext.define('User', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     fields: [
         {name: 'DeviceID', type: 'string'},
         {name: 'VehicleNo',  type: 'string'}
     ]
 });

    var store1 = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    // store configs
    model: 'User',
    storeId: 'myStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'combobox.php',
        id:'1', //show only the group ID is 1,this id are flexible,not necessary is 1
        fields: ['DeviceID','VehicleNo']
    } 
});
```

### this is the code on the toolbar

```
xtype: 'combobox',
labelWidth: 50,
labelAlign: 'right',
fieldLabel: 'Vehicle',
name: 'state1',
width :180,
store: store1,
valueField: 'DeviceID',
displayField: 'VehicleNo',
typeAhead: true,
queryMode: 'local',
emptyText: 'Select a Vehicle...'
```

### combobox.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("db_gps") or die("Could not select database");
$parent_id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT DeviceID as id, VehicleNo as text FROM Tbl_device WHERE GroupID='".$parent_id."' ORDER BY text ASC";
$rs = mysql_query($query);
$arr = array();
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
 $arr[] = $obj;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

### Mysql Database

```
delimiter $$

    CREATE TABLE `tbl_device` (
      `MainID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `DeviceID` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
      `VehicleNo` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `GroupID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `AutoPic` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`MainID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

### Question

1)i can't display the combobox data ?is that any problem with my code? please help,thanks.on my code i m trying to pass the parameter of id, u can see from my code i m passing id:1 to combobox.php, this passing value are flexible, not necessary is 1 only
2)is this code data model are correct?with DeviceID and VehicleNo fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to explicitly call the Store's load function in order to load the data into the Store via the configured proxy :

```
store1.load();
```

Other than that, you might want to check the data being returned to the `php` block by the query. Also check the `json` being returned to the client using firebug or something similar.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**:

Or, like bmoeskau said, include `autoLoad: true` in the store config

Comment: Or include `autoLoad: true` in the store config, whichever is most appropriate.